# Thymeleaf: Display data from two JPA entity tables on same page

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, Hibernate and JPA to develop this application. I have mapped a relationship between the two entities I need to retrieve data from and am wondering how to display data from the two tables on the page where the customer views his orders.

In my controller class I add the object `"viewmyorders"` to the ModelAndView, which will contain the results from my HQL query from the two tables/entities. What syntax should I use on my Thymeleaf template to display the data on the page? Will the results from both tables be preceeded with 
    `"${viewmyorder.}"`?       And what follows after the `"."` - the name of the relevant column in the database?

Help appreciated!

Orders Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Orders {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "orderno")
private int id;

@Column(name = "item_name")
private String itemName;

@Column(name = "description")
private String itemDescription; 

@Column(name = "cost")
private String cost;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
@JoinColumn(name = "orderId")  
private Customer customerInfo;

//getters and setters
}
```

Customer class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "cust_id")
private int cust_id;

@Column(name = "fName")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "surName")
private String surName; 

@Column(name = "address")
private String address;

@Column(name = "phone")
private String phone;

@Column(name = "orderId")
private int orderId;

@Column(name = "active")
private int isactive;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="customerInfo")
private Orders orderInfo; 

//getters and setters
}
```

Repository class:

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Orders, Integer> {

//customerInfo is the object (of type orders) which maps the relationship between the two entities
String MYORDERQUERY = "SELECT ord, cust from Orders ord inner join ord.customerInfo cust";

@Query(MYSWAPSQUERY)
List<Orders> findMyOrders();    
}
```

Controller method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value={"/viewmyorders"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView viewOrders(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    //orderService calls method above from Repository class to return order info
    modelAndView.addObject("viewmyorders", orderService.listAllOrders());
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Table on Thymeleaf template page:

```
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Order Number</th>
                            <th>Product Description</th>
                            <th>Delivery Address</th>
                            <th>Contact Number</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr th:each="viewmyorder : ${viewmyorders}">
                            <td th:text="${viewmyorder.orderno}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${viewmyorder.description}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${viewmyorder.address}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${viewmyorder.phone}"></td>
                        </tr>                       
                    </table>
```

Comment: In your controller, you lack a " from addObject method. What does your orderService.listAllOrders() method do? Does it invoke OrderRepository's findAll() or your custom findMyOrders query? You specify a MYORDERQUERY string in your repository but add MYSWAPSQUERY as parameter to your custom query. Even that query looks invalid, I think it should be something like ...inner join Customer cust on ord.customerInfo = cust.info, if I assume that your other entity is called Customer and it has an info column. Please provide some more code and clear up the existing codebase.

Comment: To your exact question, I would create a DTO class which has all the fields the two entity has, and make your findMyOrders() query's return type a list of that DTO object, e.g. List<OrderWithCustomerDataDTO>. Then you can add that list to your modelAndView in the controller and can refer to it's fields as objectName.fieldName

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. I'm surprised that it's necessary to have a single class to represent attributes from both db tables to solve this problem. I have mapped the relationship between my Customer table and Orders table in their respective model classes. Regarding my query above, there is no need for a "join ON" when using HQL.

Comment: Ok, take a look at my answer please, and let me know if I misunderstand the case.

Comment: You should not store an orderId in your Customer entity. Or you should change the direction of the relation. If you do that: in Orders entity remove @JoinColumn and set @OneToOne(mappedBy="orderInfo"). In Customer entity: add @JoinColumn(name = "orderno") and remove mappedBy attribute. In your DB you have to add a column in your customer table called orderno, but not in the java entity! And the name of it must be the same as your Orders' entity id, so not orderId.

Answer (score 2):

If your `Orders` entity has a `Customer` field, e.g.

```
 @Entity
 class Orders {
    ...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
    ...
 }


 @Entity 
 class Customer { 
    ... 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    @NotNull
    private Long id;
    ...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer") 
    private Orders orders; 
    ... 
 }
```

then your `OrderRepository`'s `findAll()` method gives a list of `Orders` entity that will contain `Customer` data as well. You can pass that list to your Thymeleaf template as you did in the controller, then refer to the `Customer` data as e.g. `${viewmyorders.customer.address}`

**Edit:**
Of course not only `findAll()` but any query that returns all the `Orders` entity's columns will contain `Customer` data, your custom query's result too.

**Edit #2:**
I think you want somethink like this:
Database schema and entities:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_id INT NOT NULL,
  item_name    VARCHAR(20),
  description    VARCHAR(50),
  cost       VARCHAR(20)
);


CREATE TABLE customer (
  cust_id    INT         NOT NULL,
  fName      VARCHAR(20),
  surName  VARCHAR(20),
  address        VARCHAR(50),
  phone     VARCHAR(15),
  active INT,
  order_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders (order_id)
);



@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Orders {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "order_id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "item_name")
private String itemName;

@Column(name = "description")
private String itemDescription; 

@Column(name = "cost")
private String cost;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "orderInfo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
private Customer customerInfo;

//getters and setters
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "cust_id")
private int cust_id;

@Column(name = "fName")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "surName")
private String surName; 

@Column(name = "address")
private String address;

@Column(name = "phone")
private String phone;

@Column(name = "active")
private int isactive;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id")  // This will map the primary key of orders table to the column named order_id in customer table (see SQL above), you do not need to create a field for it in java entity
private Orders orderInfo;
 // Later you can reference order_id through a Customer like customer.getOrderInfo().getId(); 

//getters and setters
```

}

Comment: Thank you - just to confirm in relation to the above example: The id (PK) for the Orders table is being mapped to the "customer_id" column in the Customer table, is that the case?

Comment: Because the findAll() method in my repository class is now returning data from both entities with the syntax you suggest above, however the data is not linked - when shown on my Thymeleaf page, the data from both tables is simply appearing in order according to each table's primary key.

Comment: Assuming your Customer entity is something like this: 
`@Entity
 class Customer {
    ...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer")
    private Orders orders;
    ...
 }`, it should work correctly, so return data that are related.

Comment: So in both of your entities must be a field of the other entity and specify their relationship with annotations. In one of them you have to tell on which column you want to join and in the other you have to set the field name referring to that entity in the other entity.

Comment: Thank you - this is useful. However I want to join my Orders entity with my Customer entity by linking the "orderid" field in my Customer table to the primary key in my Orders table. How should my entity classes look with this in mind?

Comment: I edited my answer again. Note the foreign key in the customer DB table that refers to the primary key of the orders table. But you really do not need to create a field for it in Customer java entity, JPA will map orderInfo.id to the order_id database column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149528/discussion-between-james-and-tamas-g).

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to reach the attributes your Order object has, because your service class returns a List of Orders, when looping through this list your viewmyorder will have the same attributes as your Order has.

For syntax, referencing: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html#spring-model-attributes

Comment: Thank you, I am already displaying data from a single model object on other pages in the application. But how can I show the Customer data beside the Order data in the same page?

Comment: Of course you can add as many attributes as you want, so for example you will have a modelAndView.addObject("viewmycustomers, customerService.listAllCustomers()); and with the same technique you can loop through this list too.

Comment: and sorry, if you want the Customer data as part of an Order, then you should connect the classes too, so your Order should have a Customer attribute and when you select the orders, the customer will be populated, too.

Comment: Thanks again, the issue is that I want to link the data from the 2 tables because they are related. Is this possible using the method you just described? i.e. show the order data in the same row as the info relating to the customer who placed that order?

Comment: Yes, but do you use JPA? Hibernate? Because if you use nice entities, then with some annotations you can make it. Would you please share your Order and Customer classes?

Comment: Yes, I am using JPA & Hibernate. I have added these 2 classes as requested.